# Search all sites for my posts with a specific tag

Tags: support, search

How do I search all sites I am a part of (e.g., `user:me`) for posts I made with a specific tag (e.g., `[accessibility]`)?

Is this possible on the mobile or mobile web browser platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible (even not on the desktop version of the website), unless you use the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/527462?AccountId=6085540&TagName=bug) – if you follow the link, you'll see all my [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) questions across the entire Stack Exchange network.

For reference, here is the query:

```sql
declare @AccountId int = ##AccountId##
-- AccountId: The account ID of your network profile, e.g. http://stackexchange.com/users/6085540/glorfindel:
declare @TagName nvarchar(35) = ##TagName:string##
-- TagName: The tag you're looking for

-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE

declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #posts (site nvarchar(250), id int, title nvarchar(250), body nvarchar(max));

open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) + ';
    insert into #posts 
    select ''' + QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) + ''', p.id, p.title, p.body
      from posts as p inner join posttags as pt on p.id = pt.postid
        inner join tags as t on t.id = pt.tagid
        inner join users as u on p.owneruserid = u.id
        where t.tagname = ''' + cast(@TagName as nvarchar) + '''
          and u.accountid = ' + cast(@AccountId as nvarchar);

    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select * from #posts
```

Comment: Too bad I cannot save a query somewhere on the app or web interface. Is it that too many custom queries would put too much burden on the site?

Comment: @JackMaddington you *can* save it by bookmarking the URL, or adding the query as one of your favourites in SEDE.

Comment: I know how to bookmark a post (and I regret that some bookmarked posts have disappeared). But how do I bookmark a query in SEDE? What is SEDE? I think of a post is deleted then others who have bookmarked it should still be able to see it.

Comment: @JackMaddington more details about SEDE can be found [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/help). You'll need to create an account to be able to add queries as favourites.

Comment: @Jack SEDE is shortcut for Stack Exchange Data Explorer, it's a website which works with a data dump of Stack Exchange, and each query got a unique URL. You can save this URL in your browser's bookmarks, or your mobile device Notes, then access it whenever you want.

Comment: How often is the data dump updated, and can I retrieve old dumps? Thanks.

Comment: And if so, then can I query them? Thanks.

Comment: Once a week, on Sunday morning (this is mentioned in the FAQ which I linked to already). Old dumps are stored [here](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) but cannot be queried.